# Change the default implementation with an extension in unit tests

Tags: swift, unit-testing

I have a simple protocol called `Loggable` that I want to use to create log entries in my app. The default implementation of the protocol is done with the use of an extension. I want to change that default implementation on my tests to discard any logs on the console while the app is being tested.

```
protocol Loggable {
    func log(message: String, level: LogLevel, customAttributes: [String : AnyObject]?, filename: NSString, line: Int, function: String)
}
```

So, the default implementation is something like:

```
extension Loggable {
    func log(message: String, level: LogLevel = .Debug, customAttributes: [String : AnyObject]? = nil, filename: NSString = #file, line: Int = #line, function: String = #function) {
        // Log internally
        InternalLog.log(message, level: level, customAttributes: customAttributes, filename: filename, line: line, function: function)
        // Log remotely
        // Fabric, LogEntries ?!
    }
}
```

In the unit test I'm doing:

```
extension Loggable {
    func log(message: String, level: LogLevel = .Debug, customAttributes: [String : AnyObject]? = nil, filename: NSString = #file, line: Int = #line, function: String = #function) {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

The problem is that all the logs are being printed when I run the test suite. It never uses the extension of `Loggable` added on the unit test.

I know that *Swift Extensions* can not override but this example is using different targets.

Any nature way to achieve my idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protocol extensions don't use dynamic dispatch which means that any type conforming to that protocol will only use extensions available at compile time or its own implementation if implemented.

In your case, the test target can define another protocol extension but to be used within your test target only, it won't affect your other target which was already compiled and wasn't aware of this other extension.